# Uncaught Error injector modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Uncaught Error injector modulerr Module Error.
Angular router not working properly.
After adding $stateProvider in app.config the angulerjs stop working by giving following error.

`Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/unpr?p0=%24st...
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:7:76
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:46:64
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:43:309)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:44:39)
    at Object.invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:44:124)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:42:279)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:42:418
    at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:8:7)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:42:180)
    at gb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js:46:250`

Was also giving error `Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider Stateprovider` after some changes which i didn't remember.

## Script

`    angular.module('app', [])
        'use strict';

```
   var app = angular.module('app').factory('AuthInterceptor', [function () {
        return {
            // Send the Authorization header with each request
            'request': function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                var encodedString = btoa("admin:admin");
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encodedString;
                return config;
            }
        };
    }]);


    app.config(['$httpProvider', '$stateProvider',function ($httpProvider, $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('GradesData', {
      url: '/GradesData',
      templateUrl: '../GradesData.html'
    })
    .state('GradesForm', {
      url: '/GradesForm',
      templateUrl: '../GradesForm.html'
    })

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');

}]);`
```

## included the following script

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>`

Problem Started after adding **$stateProvider**
Added $stateProvider for passing data/values from on angularjs page another angularjs page.

## other jquery script included

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>` use `$routeProvider` instead of `$stateProvider`

Then you're code will looks like that :

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
      function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
         $routeProvider
.when('/GradesData', {
         templateUrl: '../GradesData.html'})
.when('/GradesForm', {
         templateUrl: '../GradesForm.html'
            });
            $routeProvider.otherwise('/');
        }
    ]);
```

Add `ngRoute` to `angular.module`

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
```

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

For `$stateProvider` add `ui.router` to `angular.module`

```
angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router']);
```

and use

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.20/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

look up here: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld